# Can't get overlay to show up in javascript, but could in jquery

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, dom-manipulation

I want an overlay to show up when I click a search icon.

I managed to get it working using jQuery. But can't seem to get it working with javascript.

The click event does not seem to be registering and I don't know why.

I've checked all the class names so they match in the same in both the HTML and javascript

**Here is the jQuery code that works:**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Search {
  constructor() {
    this.openButton = $('.js-search-trigger');
    this.closeButton = $('.search-overlay__close');
    this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay");
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.openButton.on('click', this.openOverlay.bind(this));
    this.closeButton.on('click', this.closeOverlay.bind(this));
  }

  openOverlay() {
    this.searchOverlay.addClass("search-overlay--active");
  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.searchOverlay.removeClass("search-overlay--active");
  }
}

export default Search;
```

**Here is the javascript code that does not work:**

```
class Search {
  constructor() {
    this.openButton = document.querySelector('.js-search-trigger');
    this.closeButton = document.querySelector('.search-overlay__close');
    this.searchOverlay = document.querySelector('.search-overlay');
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.openButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.openOverlay.bind(this);
    });

    this.closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.closeOverlay.bind(this);
    });
  }

  openOverlay() {
    this.searchOverlay.classList.add('search-overlay--active');
  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.searchOverlay.classList.remove('search-overlay--active');
  }
}

export default Search;
```

No errors were shown in the javascript where the overlay was not showing.

Comment: `$('selector')` gives back a **collection** of elements. `document.querySelector('selector')` gives back only one element, the first to match. So   whatever you're doning, without `forEach`-ing your elements it will never be like the jQuery one. And event tje jQuery one will fail if you have multiple overlay elements.

Comment: The `function() { }` wrappers around the `.bind()` results are the cause of your problems.

Comment: Work to understand the scope of `this` and closure

Comment: This is a good reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/125981 question on the subject of the issue.  See if you can get the "with this" vs "on this" difference

Comment: So, how many `search-overlay`s will you have and how many `.js-search-trigger` buttons do you plan to have?

Comment: Thanks for the resource Mark Schultheiss. I used querySelector as there is only one .search-overlay and one .js-search-trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to change your event listeners to use the correct `this` binding:

```
this.openButton.addEventListener("click", this.openOverlay.bind(this));
```

Or use an arrow function to go with your approach - but make sure you actually *call* the resulting function, as in the above approach the function is passed as a reference and is called. If you removed the additional `()` from the code below, it would be the same as writing a function out in your code normally - it would be defined, but nothing would happen.

```
this.openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  this.openOverlay.bind(this)();
});
```

jQuery also uses collections of elements rather than single elements, so if you have multiple elements, `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` might be in order.

Comment: This is what you want

Comment: pretty much what I would have said for `this` which confuses new users.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss, always nice to hear the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If we are speaking of ecmascript-6 (I see the tag), I would recommend to use arrow function to have `this` inherited from the above scope, and no bind is needed:

```
    this.openButton.addEventListener('click', () => 
      this.openOverlay()
    );
```

The problems with your code are that a) the `function` creates new scope with its own `this`; b) bound methods are not being invoked.

Comment: I don't think this would work because you still don't call the function resulting from `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Why *Search*? You're creating an **Overlay**. Stick with the plan.
No need to bind anything. Use `Event.currentTarget` if you want to.
No need to handle *.open*/*.close* if all you need is a **toggle**.

And the below should work (as-is) for multiple Overlays. The overlay content is up to you.

```js
class Overlay {

  constructor() {
    this.toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-overlay]');
    if (this.toggleButtons.length) this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.toggleButtons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', this.toggleOverlay));
  }

  toggleOverlay(ev) {
    const btn = ev.currentTarget;
    const sel = btn.getAttribute('data-overlay');
    const overlay = sel ? document.querySelector(sel) : btn.closest('.overlay');
    overlay.classList.toggle('is-active');
  }

}

new Overlay();
```

```css
*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;} html,body {height:100%; font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 5vw;
  
  transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility 0.4s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-overlay="#search">OPEN #search</button>
<button type="button" data-overlay="#qa">OPEN #qa</button>

<div class="overlay" id="search">
  <button type="button" data-overlay>CLOSE</button>
  <h2>SEARCH</h2>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search&hellip;">
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="qa">
  <button type="button" data-overlay>CLOSE</button>
  <h2>Q&amp;A</h2>
  <ul><li>Lorem ipsum</li></ul>
</div>
```

The above is still not perfect, still misses a way to "destroy" events and not re-attach duplicate events to already initialised buttons when trying to target dynamically created ones.

Also, the use of Classes for the above task is absolutely misleading and unnecessary.